# Calling tk.Tk() once but unexpectedly get two windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using python 3.8.5 and tkinter 8.6.  I am learning to use tkinter.  I was trying to make a simple form but for some reason I get two windows when I run my code.  One of these windows has everything I am expecting with all the details I expect, but then there is a second unexepected uncallwed window with nothing in it.  I cannot tell from my code why there is a second window as I only have one line where I call `window.mainloop()` as well as I only create 1 window variable.

```
import tkinter as tk

WIDTH=50
HEIGHT=1
BG="white"
FG="black"

COMPONENTS_MAP = (
    {"label":"Name","type":"text"},
    {"label":"Description","type":"text_area"},
    {"type":"submit"}
)
    
COMPONENTS = []

for mapping in COMPONENTS_MAP:
    if mapping["type"] == "text_area":
        COMPONENTS.append(
            tk.Label(
                text=mapping["label"],
                foreground=FG,
                background=BG,
                width=WIDTH
            )
        )
        COMPONENTS.append(
            tk.Text(
                fg=FG,
                bg=BG,
                width=WIDTH,
                height=3
            )
        )
    if mapping["type"] == "text":
        COMPONENTS.append(
            tk.Label(
                text=mapping["label"],
                foreground=FG,
                background=BG,
                width=WIDTH
            )
        )
        COMPONENTS.append(
            tk.Entry(
                fg=FG,
                bg=BG,
                width=WIDTH
            )
        )
    if mapping["type"] == "submit":
        COMPONENTS.append(
            tk.Button(
                text="Submit",
                width=WIDTH,
                height=HEIGHT,
                bg=BG,
                fg=FG
            )
        )

window = tk.Tk()

for component in COMPONENTS:
    component.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Looks like this

[image: two windows]

Comment: You are creating various widgets before the call to `Tk()` - that's impossible without an instance of `Tk` for the widgets to live in, so one is created for you automatically.  You need to move your `Tk()` call up so that it's the very first Tkinter call that is made.

Comment: Thanks that solved it.  If you make a reply I will give you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `window` after initializing of widgets. Move `window = tk.Tk()` to begin of your code (right after importing for example).